# Perl Imager: how do I make the alpha channel become black insead of white?

Tags: perl, image-processing, png, jpeg, alpha-transparency

I wrote this code to convert a PNG image to JPEG:

```
use Imager;
use strict;

my $img = Imager->new( file => './fsc.png' );
$img = $img->convert( preset => 'noalpha' );
$img = $img->scale( xpixels => 100 );
$img->write( type => 'jpeg', file => './fsc.jpg' );
```

When passing a PNG with alpha channel (transparent), the background becomes black. What I would like to do is to have it white, instead.

Curiously, if I just write:

```
my $img = Imager->new( file => './fsc.png' );
$img->write( type => 'jpeg', file => './fsc.jpg' );
```

the jpeg has white background, but of course it's not scaled to the size I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a suggestion by the author of Imager, it seems that the most straightforward solutions is this:

```
use Imager;

my $img = Imager->new( file => './fsc.png' );
$img = $img->scale( xpixels => 100 );
$img->write( type => 'jpeg', file => './fsc.jpg', i_background => Imager::Color->new("#FFF") );
```

That is, the *i_background* parameter to save does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with Perl's **Imager** module, but I looked through the documentation and can't find anything related to setting the background colour which is what happens in other packages (e.g. **gd**, **ImageMagick**) to transparent pixels when you turn off the alpha mask.

Forgive me if this is miles more vague than any of my other answers, but it may get you started. I *think* you may need to do the following:

- create a new, white image (without alpha) the same size as your PNG
- composite your image over the new, white background

I suspect the second step above will look something like:

```
$white = $white->compose(src=>$img)
```

You *may* also need to add `mask=>$img` to the arguments, and you *may* also need to experiment with `opacity=>0.5` or `1.0` or `0.0`.

If anyone knows better, just tell me and I will delete this answer!

Comment: I accepted this answer because it indeed solves the problem (thank you). It still feels a bit awkward to have to do all of this when a simple parameter when opening the image would do. I'll open an issue for the Imager module.

Comment: After filing a bug to Imager, the author suggested me another solution, which seems the most straightforward and I'm adding in a different answer.